# Редактор Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Привет. Подкажите, пожалуйста, как отключить в Eclipse подсчет отступов (включил его случайно.)? Почти все горячие клавиши указанные в Ctrl+Shift+L перепробовал, не отключается.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferencies-General-Editors-Text Editors-[x] Show whitespace characters

Comment: спасибо, отключил. Просто интересно, как *** я его включил, если отключение требует нескольких переходов :)

Comment: ctrl-alt-w в принципе может быть. у меня есть есть такая комбинация.